# Fortran I/O: Specifying large record sizes

Tags: fortran

I am trying to write an array to file, where I have opened the file this way:

```
open(unit=20, FILE="output.txt", form='unformatted', access='direct', recl=sizeof(u))
```

Here, `u` is an array and `sizeof(u)` is 2730025920, which is ~2.5GB. 
When I run the program, I get an error `Fortran runtime error: RECL parameter is non-positive in OPEN statement`, which I believe means that the record size is too large.

Is there a way to handle this? One option would be to write the array in more than one write call such that the record size in each write is smaller than 2.5GB. But I am wondering if I can write the entire array in a single call.

Edit:
`u` has been declared as `double precision u(5,0:408,0:408,0:407)` 
The program was compiled as `gfortran -O3 -fopenmp -mcmodel=medium test.f`
There is some OpenMP code in this program, but the file I/O is sequential.

gfortran v 4.5.0, OS: Opensuse 11.3 on 64 bit AMD Opteron

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to write big arrays as long as it's memory permitting. It seems like you are getting integer overflow with the `sizeof` function. `sizeof` is not Fortran standard and I would not recommend using it (implementations may vary between compilers). Instead, it is a better practice to use the `inquire` statement to obtain record length. I was able to reproduce your problem with ifort and this solution works for me. You can avoid integer overflow by declaring a higher kind variable:

```
integer(kind=8) :: reclen

inquire(iolength=reclen)u 

open(unit=20,file='output.txt',form='unformatted',&
     access='direct',recl=reclen)
```

EDIT: After some investigation, this seems to be a gfortran problem. Setting a higher kind for integer `reclen` solves the problem for ifort and pgf90, but not for gfortran - I just tried this with version 4.6.2. Even though `reclen` has the correct positive value, it seems that `recl` is 32-bit signed integer internally with gfortran (Thanks @M.S.B. for pointing this out). The Fortran run-time error suggests this, and not that the value is larger than maximum. I doubt it is an OS issue. If possible, try using ifort (free for non-commercial use): [Intel Non-Commercial Software Download](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/non-commercial-software-download/).

Comment: just to add this: `sizeof` returns the number of bytes and `recl` isn't necessarily in bytes, so `inquire` is the proper way to do it.

Comment: @steabert Thanks for the addition, this is correct. An example for this is the code from OP, which would break with ifort for example - ifort assumes recl is length of array as in number of elements, and not number of bytes.

Comment: I still get the same error. Looks like its because the max value that `recl` takes is 2147483648 (2GB).

Comment: @KVM Can you please update your question with: code that shows declaration of u, which compiler you are using (include version number) and what kind of operating system is this?

Comment: @KVM If you get the same error (non-positive recl), that means recl is getting a negative value, and not value greater than maximum.

Comment: I suggest testing by using constant values for recl to see if the problem is with recl, removing other issues from the test.   Does the problem appear when you cross 2^31?   It might be that record length internally is a 32-bit signed integer, and passing 2^32 makes the value negative.   If your compiler/OS is limited to record lengths of 2^31 then you will have to break the array into pieces.  Or upgrade either the OS or compiler.

Comment: Yes, I hard-coded the value for recl and the problem appears when values cross 2^31. I guess I will have to break the array into pieces. Could you re-post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @KVM Indeed, this is a gfortran problem. Setting a higher kind for integer reclen solves the problem for ifort and pgf90, but not for gfortran (I just tried this with v4.6.2). Even though reclen has the correct positive value, it seems that recl is 32-bit signed integer internally with gfortran. The Fortran run-time error suggests this, and not that the value is larger than maximum. I doubt it is an OS issue. If possible, try using ifort (free for non-commercial use).

Comment: @IRO-bot Could you include this in your answer?

Comment: FWIW, this is GFortran bug #44292, see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44292

Comment: @janneb Thanks. I am surprised this bug is still not resolved.

Comment: @IRO-bot: Technically it's easy, but it might break the library ABI (depending on how one does it), which is a big inconvenience for users. There's a laundry list of things to do once the ABI break is done at http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LibgfortranAbiCleanup