# The most efficient way to read a unformatted file

Tags: performance, io, fortran

Now I am data-processing 100,000 files by using Fortran. These data are generated by HPC using MPI I/O. Now I can just figure out the following ways to read the raw, which is not efficient.  Is it possible that read every to read ut_yz(:,J,K), at one one time insteading of reading one by one? Thanks 
The old code is as follows and the efficiency is not so high.

```
  OPEN(10,FILE=trim(filename)//".dat",FORM='UNFORMATTED',&
           ACCESS='DIRECT', RECL=4, STATUS='OLD')
      !,CONVERT='big_endian'
      COUNT = 1
      DO K=1,nz
         DO J=1,ny
            DO I=1,nxt
              READ(10,REC=COUNT) ut_yz(I,J,K)
              COUNT = COUNT + 1
            ENDDO
         ENDDO
      ENDDO
    CLOSE(10)
```

The desired one is

```
 OPEN(10,FILE=trim(filename)//".dat",FORM='UNFORMATTED', RECL=4, STATUS='OLD')
      !,CONVERT='big_endian'
      COUNT = 1
      DO K=1,nz
         DO J=1,ny
              READ(10,REC=COUNT) TEMP(:)
          COUNT = COUNT + 153
          ut_yz(:,J,K)=TEMP(:)
         ENDDO
      ENDDO
    CLOSE(10)
```

However, it always fails.  Can anyone make a comment on this? Thanks.

Comment: You say the data were written using MPI I/O, so are you sure you want to be using direct access rather than stream Fortran IO?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct recl? Having this hardcoded is not advisable, as the length might be expressed differently in different compilers. Better use inquire to get the correct number, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/9014149/577108

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark sorry for the unclear description,  the error message is Fortran runtime error: Non-existing record number. And now the problem is solved by using inquire as suggested by haraldkl

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for your suggestion.                                             call MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL(fh, wk, &
            subsizes(1)*subsizes(2)*subsizes(3), &
            real_type, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierror) is used to out put the data. Can you give me an example of using stream Fortran IO. Thanks.

Comment: If the whole array you want to read in is written by that single collective write then opening with `access='stream'` followed by a single read of the whole array should/could suffice.  [I thought there was a similar question asked, but I can't find it.]

Comment: @francescalus Thanks. I will try to find the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct IO read will read a single record, if I am not mistaken. Thus, in your new code version you need to increase the record length accordingly:

```
   inquire(iolength=rl) ut_yz(:,1,1)
   open(10, file=trim(filename)//'.dat', form='UNFORMATTED', recl=rl, status='OLD', action='READ')
   count = 1
   do k=1,nz
     do j=1,ny
       read(10, rec=count) ut_yz(:,j,k)
       count = count + 1
     end do
   end do
   close(10)
```

Of course, in this example you could also read the complete array at once, which should be the fastest option:

```
   inquire(iolength=rl) ut_yz
   open(10, file=trim(filename)//'.dat', form='UNFORMATTED', recl=rl, status='OLD', action='READ')
   read(10, rec=1) ut_yz
   close(10)
```